# Multithreading in python2 vs python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, python-2.x, gil

I'm familiar with Python's GIL, and so I know that multithreading is not really multithreading in Python.

When I ran the code below, I expected the result would be 0, because the GIL won't allow a race condition to exist. In python3, the result was 0. But in python2, it was not 0; the result was an unexpected one like -3492 or 21283.

How do I solve the problem?

```
import threading 
x = 0 # A shared value

def foo(): 
  global x 
  for i in range(100000000): 
    x += 1 

def bar(): 
  global x 
  for i in range(100000000):
    x -= 1 

t1 = threading.Thread(target=foo) 
t2 = threading.Thread(target=bar) 

t1.start() 
t2.start() 

t1.join() 
t2.join() # Wait for completion

print(x)
```

Comment: I would strongly advise against people running this; it could lock up your machine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The statement `x += 1` is not threadsafe in any version of Python. The fact that you were seeing the results of the a race condition in Python 2 but not Python 3 is mostly just a coincidence (it probably has to do with optimizations for when the GIL switches between threads, but I don't know the details). It could get the wrong results in Python 3 too.

The reason is that the `+=` operator is not atomic. It requires several bytecodes to run, and the GIL is only guaranteed to prevent switching between threads while any one bytecode is running. Lets look at a disassembly of your `foo` function to see how it works (this is from Python 3.7, in Python 2.7 the addresses within the bytecode are different, but all the operations are the same):

```
>>> dis.dis(foo)
  3           0 SETUP_LOOP              24 (to 26)
              2 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (range)
              4 LOAD_CONST               1 (100000000)
              6 CALL_FUNCTION            1
              8 GET_ITER
        >>   10 FOR_ITER                12 (to 24)
             12 STORE_FAST               0 (i)

  4          14 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (x)
             16 LOAD_CONST               2 (1)
             18 INPLACE_ADD
             20 STORE_GLOBAL             1 (x)
             22 JUMP_ABSOLUTE           10
        >>   24 POP_BLOCK
        >>   26 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             28 RETURN_VALUE
```

The lines we care about are the four with bytecode positions 14-20. The first two load the arguments to the addition. The third does the `INPLACE_ADD` operation. The result of the addition gets put back on the stack, because not all types of objects can be updated in place (integers cannot, so it's necessary here). The last bytecode stores the sum back to the original name.

If the interpreter chooses to switch which thread holds the GIL in between when we load `x` in bytecode 14 and when we store the new value to it again in bytecode 20, we'll probably end up with an incorrect result, as the value we loaded earlier may not be valid any more when we get get hold of the GIL again.

As I mentioned above, the fact that you get `0` in Python 3 is simply the result of an implementation detail, that the interpreter choose not to switch during that critical section of bytecode in the time you were testing it. There's no guarantee it won't choose differently if you run the program again in another situation (e.g. under heavy CPU load), or in a different interpreter version (e.g. 3.7 instead of 3.6, or whatever).

If you want real thread safety, then you should use actual locks, not rely solely on the GIL. The GIL only ensures that the interpreter's internal state remains sane. It doesn't guarantee that every line of your code is atomic.